# Clear title property while JQuery tooltip shows

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using some very simple JQuery to create a hovering tool tip using text stored in elements' `title` attribute.  It's working okay, but I need to stop the browser's default `title` behaviour occurring at the same time (or after the slight delay on hover).

[image]

I think JQuery's `.on()` functionality may not be the best way, although I am trying to use the latest functionality (that I am aware of!).

Currently if I clear the existing `title` value, the actual tooltip appears but is empty.  I think that is because the code runs continuously while the mouse is over the element.

[image]

Can anyone offer a way to stop the browser's `title` text appearing, but restore the original value of `title` onmouseout?  I need the code to work with JQuery 1.10.1+ with XHTML1.1 compatibility.

Thanks.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('<div/>', { id: 'ttfloat', 'class': 'tooltip' }).appendTo('body');
        BuildTipsV3();
    });

    function pageLoad() { // fired by ASP.NET after partial postback
        BuildTipsV3();
    }

    //var temptt;

    function BuildTipsV3() {
        $("[title]").on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                var o = $(this).offset();
                var y = o.top + 18;
                var x = o.left;
                temptt = $(this).attr("title"); // temp storage
                $(this).data('title', temptt);
                //$(this).attr('title', '');
                var tooltip = temptt;
                tooltip = tooltip.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br/>");
                $("#ttfloat").css({top:y, left:x})
                             .html(tooltip)
                             .show();
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $("#ttfloat").hide();
                $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('title')); // reset for accessibility
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: To remove the 'title' attribute in your mouseenter function, use `$(this).removeAttr('title');` (you may have to use `removeProp()` instead, not sure offhand)

Comment: Or you could use one of the many tooltip plugins already in existence and not re-invent the wheel. Just sayin...

Comment: I've tried about ten plug-ins already.  They all require far too much 'wiring' code.  This functionality is destined for use on a huge enterprise application with large pages, so needs to be ultra-lightweight

Comment: `$(this).removeAttr('title');` does in indeed work perfectly.  I was trying to clear the title instead, which was failing.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Added it as an answer. You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making these lines:

```
temptt = $(this).attr("title"); // temp storage
$(this).data('title', temptt);
//$(this).attr('title', '');
var tooltip = temptt;
```

do this instead:

```
var $this = $(this),
    tooltip = $this.attr('title') || $this.data('title');
$this
    .attr('title', '')
    .data('title', tooltip);
```

What the code above does is that if the title attribute is empty, the or (`||`) operator will then look for the title within the data.

Comment: This works very well also.  Could you please offer any clarity as to whether your version or Derek's above is any better?  Thanks.

Comment: `removeAttr('title')` completely removes the title attribute while `attr('title','')` makes it's value an empty string, either way no default title tooltip will appear. I think the issue here was that the title would sometimes be empty thus clearing the stored data and the displayed tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(selector).removeAttr('title');` to achieve your desired results.